# Deleted fragment_my.xml mistakenly? how to regenerate it?

Tags: android

I am new to android and it is my first project which I have started . While working with design view of `fragment_my.xml` file I have mistakenly deleted content in xml file. How can I regenerate it ?

Note: I am using Android Studio for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new xml in the same folder with the same name i.e. fragment_my.xml
It will recreate your old xml file with full data.

Comment: Do I need to delete old one first as it content is deleted, file still exists and I need to create a layout xml file.Right?

Comment: If only content is deleted then press Control+Z
it will undo all of your changes..

Comment: Thanks for the help bro.. I forgot about that ctrl+Z  magical option..I got a little too technical about this one :D

Answer (score 3):

Try the following option that may help you.

Right click on your Project in eclipse there will an option called `Restore from Local History...`

```
Project -> RightClick -> Restore from Local History...
```

**Recover a Deleted Project in Android Studio**

If the project has not been deleted from the file system select the project from the Open Project option else had to use Recovery-software [For more details](http://tekeye.biz/2014/delete-project-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am using android studio for this.How to do it it android studio?

Comment: I am not trying to recover complete project.I just want to recreate my fragment_my.xml file